# Correct sql (arel) for this query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I have two tables, one with `users`, the other with `profiles`. Each table has a `created_at` column, where I want to update `profiles.created_at` so that it is the same as the corresponding row (determined by `user_id`) in `users.created_at`.

In Rails, I might do something like:

`Profile.update_all(created_at: {???})`

Trying to create an efficient query as this is being performed on over a million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update  profiles p 
set     p.created_at = (select  u.created_at 
                        from    users u 
                        where   u.user_id = p.user_id 
                        and     u.created_at <> p.created_at
                        )
```

Comment: Thanks! Any reason for `created_at <> created_at` clause?

Comment: I included that clause to avoid writing to records where the created_at fields already match. (Why take cycles rewriting data that is already correct).